# JavaScript `promt` will not execute at beginning of script

Tags: javascript

This is a small simple issue, I am beginning to learn JavaScript and currently testing else if statements as well as a 'prompt' action. However this action will not execute there for I can't give the 'Chicken' a value

What exactly did I do wrong?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
function state(){
 var chicken = promt("insert value");
 var alive = 1;
 var dead = 2;

 if (chicken == alive)
 {
  document.write("Chicken is Alive");
 }
 else if 
 {
  document.write("Chicken is Dead");
 }
}

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You misspelt `prompt`. (Voting off-topic: typo)

Comment: You never call `state` either, but that looks like a flaw in your [mcve] rather than being relevant to your question.

Comment: and your `else if` line has no condition in it

Comment: Your browser has developer tools. Learn how to use them. Error messages are handy things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some comments to the code below hope it helps!

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function state(){
        var chicken = prompt("insert value");
        var alive = 1;
        var dead = 2;

        //compare string to number? this chicken will never be alive! 
    //What if user types "maybe", we would compare 'maybe' == 1 //false

     if (chicken == alive)
        {
          document.write("Chicken is Alive");
        }
        // you will always kill the chicken! you missed condition
        else if (alive < 3)
        {
          document.write("Chicken is Dead");
        }
      }

      //remember to call the function!
      state()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your comments are very useful

Comment: Actually the comparisons are fine, because the `==` operator will give `true` for the number `1` and the string `"1"`, and similarly for other numbers. (It wouldn't work if `===` had been used, though.) The other comments are valid though.

Comment: I know I realized later it was a prompt and had double equality but such prompt is not validated as number only so we could be comparing strings to numbers at some point and not just 2 == '2'

Answer (score 0):

You did not call the state function after defining it. In addition to markymarks answer, it is also good practice to load user javascript after the page finishes loading.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Thanks. This is all very new to me and is coming in very handy